# django2 css sometimes not found produces 404 error

Tags: css, django

Using Django 2.2 (Ubuntu 19.04 and python3.7) and learning to add some css (and js) for the first time. Trying with a single app called homepage, to produce a visual homepage with three pages with some static.

I get intermittent css 'file not found' 404 errors which I've been unable to resolve using many solutions listed in Django docs and on stackoverflow.

I've followed django2.2 docs folder structure with app (homepage) under static/homepage each with its own folder and also tried:-

a. Moving css, js, images folders to web1/static (global static) and to web1/static/homepage (no sub folders)
b. using and adjusting STATIC_ROOT AND STATIC_URL to various settings
c. adjusting static template tags using variations to match a. and with full url /web1/homepage/static/homepage/css without static tag
d. with and without url + static[] stanza in urls.py
e. css files with & without load static + tags
f. reloaded and cleared caches, tried different browsers and machine.

Project outline is :-

```
├── homepage
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── admin
│   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── fonts
│   │   │   ├── img
│   │   │   └── js
│   │   └── homepage
│   │       ├── css
│   │       ├── images
│   │       └── js
│   └── templates
│       └── homepage
├── ve37
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── python3.7
│   │       └── site-packages
│   └── lib64 -> lib
└── web1
    └── __pycache__
```

key lines in settings.py (also tried with just 'homepage' as last entry.

```
DEBUG = True
....

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'homepage.apps.HomepageConfig',
]

...............

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'homepage')
# below just for try
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(STATIC_URL, 'homepage'),]
```

head of home.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--# concept from templated AB -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Etoile Grill</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="{% static 'homepage/js/html5shiv.js' %}"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'homepage/js/skel.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'homepage/js/skel-panels.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'homepage/js/init.js' %}"></script>
        <link href="{% static 'homepage/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="{% static 'homepage/css/skel-noscript.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{% static 'homepage/css/style-desktop.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link href="{% static 'homepage/css/ie/v8.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><link href="{% static 'homepage/css/ie/v9.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body class='homepage'>

    <!-- Header -->
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo-wrapper">
                <div class="container">

                    <!-- Logo -->
                        <div id="logo">
                            <h1><a href="#">Etoile Grill </a></h1>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>          
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Nav -->
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'homepage:home' %}">Etoile Grill</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'homepage:leftsidebar' %}">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'homepage:rightsidebar' %}">Contact [Tél 31 345 6785849]</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

extract from style.css (no static tags)

```
    #body {
        background: #fefbd8 url(/static/homepage/images/banner.jpg) repeat;
    }

    body,input,textarea,select
    {
        font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
        font-size: 11pt;
        line-height: 1.75em;
    }
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6
    {
    }
```

web1 urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('homepage.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

When I launch development server I do get the expect website pages, navigations works, colours, fonts, containers, are all OK BUT always some errors:-

```
Starting development server at http://192.168.1.105:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[03/Jun/2019 18:44:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7834
Not Found: /css/style.css
Not Found: /css/style-desktop.css
[03/Jun/2019 18:44:42] "GET /css/style-desktop.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2650
[03/Jun/2019 18:44:42] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2626
```

Clearly django finds the static otherwise I wouldn't get images and page functions, right? So it's just the .css that seems to be missed.

So I think it might be something like a namespace issue when I navigate between pages

I guess I missing something simple but after several days I'm blind (or dumb) - so any clues welcomes..

Comment: If your  `STATIC_URL` is `/static/`, Django's `{% static ... %}` will _never_ emit requests for just plain `/css/...` (it would be `/static/css/...`). Are you absolutely sure there's nothing else that could request those URLs?

Comment: @AKX thanks, no, I'm not certain, but, for example, when I run ````python manage.py findstatic homepage/css/style-desktop.css --verbosity 1```` , I get as expected ````Found 'homepage/css/style-desktop.css' here:
  /home/andrew/DockerProjects/web1/homepage/static/homepage/css/style-desktop.css" ````
I ran a find in Path for ```` css/style-desktop.css````,  and got only the 3 html pages as source as expected.

Comment: @AKX : I found that if I remove my js scripts I get a clean flow, no 404 errors. So somewhere in my js there is a link back to wrong css folder. I need to learn more js to debug but happy for now to live with the basic ````  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
````

Comment: There you go then :) As I imagined, it wasn't a Django issue per se.